# Angular ajax post to FormSpree.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have currently a jQuery script that sends ajax to http://formspree.io (static form submission). Their docs say to do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "//formspree.io/you@email.com", 
  method: "POST",
  data: {message: "hello!"},
  dataType: "json" 
});
```

In my own jQuery script - I have this which also works:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://formspree.io/email@example.org",
  data: 'name=' + name + '&_replyto=' + email + '&message=' + message;,
  dataType: "json",
 });
```

However my efforts to achieve this in Angular have failed - formspree claims I am submiting an empty form.

```
$http({
  url: "http://formspree.io/email@example.org",
  data: {
    email: email,
    message: message
  },
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

$http({
  url: "http://formspree.io/email@example.org",
  data: 'email=...&message=...',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
```

I am able to do this:

```
data: 'first=hgf&last=ghfgh',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

But this causes FormSpree to think I am a non ajax I think and tries to load a thank you page. I am unclear if this is tbe reason though. I get the form but it throws errors about the thank you page.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send data in form-urlencoded format:

```
$http({
    url: "http://formspree.io/email@example.org",
    data: $.param({
        email: email,
        message: message
    }),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, seems that you also need to send `Accept: application/json` header. jQuery sends it if you specify `dataType: 'json'`.